# Swift - Change UIPageViewController view on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using an `UIPageViewController` and my intention is to switch the current view on click of a `UIButton` in one of its `UIViewController`. I've already googled my problem and found some similar threads, but I couldn't make head nor tail of the answers.

For instance, the button in my second `UIViewController` `vc2` shall change view to `vc3`.

**RootPageViewController**

```
import UIKit

class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timelineView")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView")
        let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addView")

        return [vc1, vc2, vc3]
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = self

        let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1]
        self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let previousIndex = vcIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let vcIndex = viewControllerList.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

        let nextIndex = vcIndex + 1

        guard viewControllerList.count != nextIndex else { return nil }

        guard viewControllerList.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

        return viewControllerList[nextIndex]
    }

}
```

**Button inside of second ViewController**

```
@IBAction func addData(_ sender: Any) {


    }
```

Comment: you can set notifier?

Comment: @RaviPadsala I'm sorry, but I'm new to Swift. Could you please illustrate your answer in a answer below?

Comment: you can change pagecontroller position in same class on button click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `RootPageViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` add second view controller button's target to `self` and add `addData` method to `RootPageViewController`. You can use `setViewControllers` and move to the last view controller in that method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self
    if let secondViewController = viewControllerList[1] as? SecondViewController {
        self.setViewControllers([secondViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        secondViewController.button.action = #selector(addData(_:))
    }
}
@IBAction func addData(_ sender: Any) {
    if let thirdViewController = viewControllerList.last {
        self.setViewControllers([thirdViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**OR**

Keep addData method in MainViewControlle and add a protocol to it like this

```
protocol MainVCDelegate {
    func buttonPlusTapped()
}
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var buttonPlus: UIBarButtonItem!

    var delegate: MainVCDelegate?
    @IBAction func addData(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.buttonPlusTapped()
    }
}
```

In RootPageViewController confirm to this delegate and add the delegate method

```
class RootPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, MainVCDelegate {

    func buttonPlusTapped() {
        if let thidViewController = viewControllerList.last {
            self.setViewControllers([thidViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    lazy var viewControllerList:[UIViewController] = {

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let vc1 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "timelineView")
        let vc2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainView") as! MainViewController
        vc2.delegate = self
        let vc3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addView")
        return [vc1, vc2, vc3]
    }()
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192400/discussion-on-answer-by-rajeshkumar-r-swift-change-uipageviewcontroller-view-o).